# Tween frames INSIDE a Starling MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, starling-framework

I noticed the Starling MovieClip does not expose a 'gotoAndPlay' method.
So how would you tween the frames of a Starling MovieClip?

Is it even possible?

I want to avoid having to use a traditional MovieClip and use the bitmapData draw method to generate a texture for use in a Starling Image.
Normally I would just use TweenLite and tween the frame property.

```
TweenLite.to(mc, .7, {frame:<frame number here>});
```

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
mc.currentFrame = 0; //stop on first frame

//make a repeat tween
var tweenPlay:Tween = new Tween(mc, mc.numFrames / mc.fps, Transitions.LINEAR);
tweenPlay.animate("currentFrame", mc.numFrames - 1); //0 based frames
tweenPlay.onComplete = repeatPlay;
tweenPlay.onCompleteArgs = [mc];

//add tween to juggler
Starling.current.juggler.add(tweenPlay);
```

Comment: thanks. If I understand correctly though this will just animate using a constant speed? Will give it a try

Comment: as long as you use `Transitions.LINEAR`